# @angular/CLI issue while migrating Angular from 11 to 12

Tags: migration, angular-cli

In the process of angular migration from 11 to 14. I started with 11 to 12.

I ran the below command to update from angular 11 to 12

```
ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12,
```

Got terminal message as updated successfully but angular cdk is not updated.
so I used `ng update @angular/cdk@12`. now cdk is updated to 12 but `@anular/core` and `@angular/cli` reverted back to 11.

I reverted back all the changes and thought to update all together like

```
ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12 @anular/cdk@12
```

This time `@angular/animations, @angular/forms , @angular/core, @angular/compiler` etc., upgraded with 13.3.11, only cdk updated with @12, and got many other errors.

Note: I used the combinations, but didn't work

1. ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12 @anular/cdk@12 --force
2. ng update @angular/cdk@12
   ng update @angular/cli@12
   ng update @angular/core@12

Please suggest me how to upgrade cli, core and cdk from angular11 to angular12.

Comment: do u have global cli version? (not in project)

Comment: yes. there is a angular/cli@14 installed in globally. do I need to remove that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Global cli version must be same (from 11 to 12 -> 12)
2. `ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12`
3. Commit changes
4. `ng update @angular/cdk@12 @angular/material@12`
   if some packages (not cdk & material) downgraded (u will see that if do step 3) and no changes in files - just rollback them in package.json
5. Success

Comment: 1) is ok even if they are not different versions. a temporary install will be done so they will match.